# Averaging 1 min kW values

Tags: power, electricity

I have some time series data, with values of active power every minute in kW. Now, I am not an electrical engineer, and I would like to average them out per hour.

My questions I guess are:

1. do I simply work out the mean every 60 min to work out this average value of power in kW? Is it that simple?
2. Also, if I compute the mean of the power varies in 60 min buckets, won't the final averaged value be in kWh?
3. Finally, what if I had vales in kWhh (kW per half hour)? If I took the mean of such two kWhh values (1/2hr spread), will I end up having kWh?

I am sure these are most likely daft questions, but I would like to make sure of the above before proceeding to do the analysis on the time series.

Comment: K = Kelvin. k = kilo. kWhh is the most arcane unit I have seen in a long time! Please also note that _"kWhh (kW per half hour)?"_ is kWh per half hour. Take some time and think about the difference between a kW and a kWh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Averaging (i.e. taking the mean of) a bunch of numbers do not change their units. Just like the average length of 60 sticks with a length in feet is some value in feet, the average of 60 values in kW is a value with units of kW.

So,

1. Yes, if you take the mean of the first 60 values (in kW), you will get the average power (in kW) during the first hour.
2. No, but: the energy is the mean power multiplied by time, and if your time is one hour, the number is the same but the units are different. 50 kW times 1 hour is 50 kWh.
3. No, as above, but also your unit is a bit confusing. See below.

Watts and kilowatts are a measure of power, which is *energy divided by time*.

Energy is therefore *power multiplied by time*, measured in kilowatt-hours (one kilowatt of power operating for one hour).

You talk about "kilowatts per half hour", which would be *power divided by time*, and represent something like the rate of change of power. I believe you meant an energy unit like "kilowatt-half-hours" (a kilowatt of power operating for half an hour).

Comment: Great explanation @drnoir: I REALLY understood a lot from your post - esp making me think about the area under the power vs time curve to compute energy. Yes, I had meant kilowatt-half-hours (a kilowatt of power operating for half an hour. Thank you again for the wonderfully simple explanation.

Comment: Nice to hear it helped. These ideas lead us quickly to calculus: integration is a more generation notion of "area under a curve", and the derivative gives the slope of a curve. The derivative of energy is the momentary power, and the integral of the momentary power over an interval of time is the energy during that time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you simply average Energy consumption over time.

If you realize every result is energy e.g. **kW-minutes, kW-half-hours, kWh**

You then simply **normalize any energy value** so you are using the same units in the average function, then convert to kWh, when needed.

3. Thus if you average two  kW-half-hours values OK, but o convert to Wh you need to scale x0.5 to get the final units of kWh.
   {hour per half-hour}.

Comment: Thank you @Sunnyskguy: so, just to be sure, if you average two kW-half-hours value, the result is in KWh?

Comment: no thats still in kWhh so you divide by 2 or x 0.5 to get the result to get kWh